# How to surpass cell death?

Tags: cell-biology, death, pathway

Is it possible to surpass/decay [cell death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_death).  For example to disable the process [muscles](https://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/7h2uso/new_research_has_shown_that_it_is_possible_to) cells death, by tweaking the transduction pathways:

[image]

If it's not possible in our age Medicine, what it would take to do such thing in theory. The idea is to tweak the cell dying mechanisms for example to preserve neural and muscle cells for longer time. I am also curious how to disable a pathway or part of it.

Comment: Or maybe we could block cell death to increase [cell death](http://stm.sciencemag.org/content/9/408/eaao6129.full)?!

Answer (score 3):

Yes; It is possible to inhibit cell death.

There are several possibilities, of which many - as correctly recognized by you - involve changes in the activity of the cell death pathway (or related ones);

For a long (but still incomplete) list of commercially available drugs that inhibit cell death, please see: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/cell-biology/cell-biology-products.html?TablePage=9559839

P.S.: Note that selectively inhibiting a pathway (note: not only cell-death) in only one cell type (or tissue - as you hinted at) usually requires a lot of tests and experimentation and isn't trivial.

Comment: How does the process of disabling a pathway work?

Comment: the processes will be highly drug and target specific